# Xamarin iOS camera and photos

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, camera, photo

I am taking a picture with the iOS camera and trying to extract metadata from the image. This is my code:-

```
partial void BtnCamera_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
        {
            UIImagePickerController imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController();
            imagePicker.PrefersStatusBarHidden();
            imagePicker.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;

            // handle saving picture and extracting meta-data from picture //
            imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia += Handle_FinishedPickingMedia;

            // present //
            PresentViewController(imagePicker, true, () => { });         
        }


protected void Handle_FinishedPickingMedia(object sender, UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // determine what was selected, video or image
                bool isImage = false;
                switch (e.Info[UIImagePickerController.MediaType].ToString())
                {
                    case "public.image":
                        isImage = true;
                        break;
                }

                // get common info 
                NSUrl referenceURL = e.Info[new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL")] as NSUrl;
                if (referenceURL != null)
                    Console.WriteLine("Url:" + referenceURL.ToString());
```

I am able to initiate the camera, take the picture and then however when I click 'use photo'... The referenceURL comes back as NULL... How can I get the url, such that to extract GPS coordinates of the photo and such other attributes ?

Comment: my guess is that the pictures is never saved in the gallery...

Comment: When you use camera to capture photos, there's no referenceURL. If you want to get the metadata, you can use the key `UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata`.

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT I would like an example/sample code... do you have a link for me?

Comment: I can make a sample for you. But firstly, please tell me you just need the url for what? Or the metadata can meet your requirement.

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT I want the URL to extract metadata as shown in https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/images/access_image_metadata/

Comment: So if you can get metadata directly, then the URL is not necessary? You can get it in e.Info[“UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata”]

Comment: i suppose not... but i am very new to this (basically my first crack at this).. and i am wondering if this is a tried and tested method, why not use it..

Comment: The referenceUrl won’t be null when you capture pictures from album. From your code we know you just use camera, the photo doesn’t exist in the photo album. So the url will be null. Please notice the e.Info. What you need may exist in it(e.Info[“UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata”]).

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can request a `PHAsset` from the reference Url and that will contain some metadata. You can request the image data to obtain more.

Note: If you need full EXIF, you need to check to ensure the image on on the device (could be iCloud-based), download it if needed, and then load the image data with the `ImageIO` framework (lots of SO postings cover this).

```
public void ImagePicker_FinishedPickingMedia(object sender, UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs e)
{
    void ImageData(PHAsset asset)
    {
        if (asset == null) throw new Exception("PHAsset is null");
        PHImageManager.DefaultManager.RequestImageData(asset, null, (data, dataUti, orientation, info) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data);
            Console.WriteLine(info);
        });
    }

    PHAsset phAsset;
    if (e.ReferenceUrl == null)
    {
        e.OriginalImage?.SaveToPhotosAlbum((image, error) =>
        {
            if (error == null)
            {
                var options = new PHFetchOptions
                {
                    FetchLimit = 1,
                    SortDescriptors = new[] { new NSSortDescriptor("creationDate", true) }
                };
                phAsset = PHAsset.FetchAssets(options).FirstOrDefault() as PHAsset;
                ImageData(phAsset);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        phAsset = PHAsset.FetchAssets(new[] { e.ReferenceUrl }, null).FirstOrDefault() as PHAsset;
        ImageData(phAsset);
    }
}
```

**Note**: Make sure you have request runtime photo library authorization `PHPhotoLibrary.RequestAuthorization`) and have set the `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description` string in your info.plist to avoid a nasty privacy crash

Comment: i do have that setting set in my plist.info file..however still getting a crash, I have commented out all of the lines from my FinishedPickingMedia functions, except for the ones you have noted...

Comment: Somehow the crash is in my MAin.cs UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate"); line...Unhandled Exception:

Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[NSNull scheme]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x39fb9978

Comment: What I am surprised by is that the pictures is never exclusively saved in my photo album

Comment: e.Info[UIImagePickerController.MediaType].ToString() has some info associated with photo in cache memory

Comment: however NSUrl referenceURL = e.Info[new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL")] as NSUrl;... is null

Comment: I want to use that URL to extract metdata as shown in https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/images/access_image_metadata/

Comment: e.ReferenceURL is null

Comment: ok. so now the photo is saved.. but how do I get the URL now ?

Comment: the phAsset doesn't work..crashes... with a fatal error

Comment: I see that the info contains the PHIImageFileURLKey, however... I dont see a way to extract it...

Answer (score 1):

I had a tremendous amount of trouble with the URL. It can be a file, it can be a web url and it acts different on every device. My app crashed and burned so many times with my test group. I finally found a way to get the Metadata from the data. There are multiple ways to get the DateTaken, Width and Height as well as GPS Coordinates. In addition, I needed the Camera MFG and the Model.

```
string dateTaken = string.Empty;
string lat = string.Empty;
string lon = string.Empty;
string width = string.Empty;
string height = string.Empty;
string mfg = string.Empty;
string model = string.Empty;

PHImageManager.DefaultManager.RequestImageData(asset, options, (data, dataUti, orientation, info) => {

    dateTaken = asset.CreationDate.ToString();

    // GPS Coordinates
    var coord = asset.Location?.Coordinate;
    if (coord != null)
    {
        lat = asset.Location?.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString();
        lon = asset.Location?.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString();
    }

    UIImage img = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
    if (img.CGImage != null)
    {
        width = img.CGImage?.Width.ToString();
        height = img.CGImage?.Height.ToString();
    }
    using (CGImageSource imageSource = CGImageSource.FromData(data, null))
    {
        if (imageSource != null)
        {
            var ns = new NSDictionary();
            var imageProperties = imageSource.CopyProperties(ns, 0);
            if (imageProperties != null)
            {
                width = ReturnStringIfNull(imageProperties[CGImageProperties.PixelWidth]);
                height = ReturnStringIfNull(imageProperties[CGImageProperties.PixelHeight]);

                var tiff = imageProperties.ObjectForKey(CGImageProperties.TIFFDictionary) as NSDictionary;
                if (tiff != null)
                {
                    mfg = ReturnStringIfNull(tiff[CGImageProperties.TIFFMake]);
                    model = ReturnStringIfNull(tiff[CGImageProperties.TIFFModel]);
                    //dateTaken = ReturnStringIfNull(tiff[CGImageProperties.TIFFDateTime]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

The little helper function

```
private string ReturnStringIfNull(NSObject inObj)
{
    if (inObj == null) return String.Empty;
    return inObj.ToString();
}
```