# Xamarin iOS CGImageFromUrl returns null

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, photo

I am using Xamarin iOS on windows Visual studio to extract metadata from a photo taken by the iphone camera.

```
 private void GetMetaData(NSUrl url)
        {                                 
            CGImageSource myImageSource;
            myImageSource = CGImageSource.FromUrl(url, null);
            var ns = new NSDictionary();
            var imageProperties = myImageSource.CopyProperties(ns, 0);
            var gps = imageProperties.ObjectForKey(CGImageProperties.GPSDictionary) as NSDictionary;
            var lat = gps[CGImageProperties.GPSLatitude];
            var latref = gps[CGImageProperties.GPSLatitudeRef];
            var lon = gps[CGImageProperties.GPSLongitude];
            var lonref = gps[CGImageProperties.GPSLongitudeRef];
            var loc = String.Format("GPS: {0} {1}, {2} {3}", lat, latref, lon, lonref);
            Console.WriteLine(loc);
        }
```

the url being passed into the method is as:- {file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0006.JPG}

The CGImageSource.FromUrl(url, null) returns null and my app crashes... Can anyone explain to me how I need to fix this?

**Edit** This is how I am getting the URL for the image.

```
protected void Handle_FinishedPickingMedia(object sender, UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs e)
        {
            NSUrl url = null;
            try
            {
                void ImageData(PHAsset asset)
                {
                    if (asset == null) throw new Exception("PHAsset is null");
                    PHImageManager.DefaultManager.RequestImageData(asset, null, (data, dataUti, orientation, info) =>
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine(data);
                        Console.WriteLine(info);    
                        url = info.ValueForKey(new NSString("PHImageFileURLKey")) as NSUrl;
                        // Call method to get MetaData from Image Url //
                        GetMetaData(url);

                    });
                }
```

Comment: place a try/catch around the suspect line to get the exception.  Most likely it's an invalid url - where did you come up with that path?  If you want to read data from an image in the photo library that is not the way to do it.

Comment: Here is what i am trying to mimic 
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/images/access_image_metadata/

Comment: @Jason and I extracted the path using PHAsset

Comment: Also, like i said it is a null exception..where object reference is not set..

Comment: I'm guessing that NSUrl returns a null when given an invalid argument - you need to do some debugging to chase down the source of the null ref

Comment: The source is on this line: myImageSource = CGImageSource.FromUrl(url, null);....

Comment: NsUrl is being populated correctly. (It is not null), the format might need a change

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/112710/why-would-cgimagesource-fromurl-return-null

Comment: do you realize that there are no answers to that ? I have seen that link before I posted on here.

Comment: that's why I didn't post it as an answer.  Other people are having this problem, so it may be worth submitting a bug to Xamarin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in your last post: [Xamarin iOS camera and photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49203247/xamarin-ios-camera-and-photos): If you capture photos from camera, the event will not return a `ReferenceUrl`. But you can get the metadata info with another key:

```
protected void Handle_FinishedPickingMedia(object sender, UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs e)
{
    var metadataInfo = e.Info["UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata"]; //or e.MediaMetadata;
}
```

This will contain some basic information which may be helpful to you. But this `NSDictionary` doesn't contain the GPS information. Because this picture is created by yourself, you should get the GPS by using `CLLocationManager` manually:

```
CLLocationManager manager;
manager = new CLLocationManager();
manager.RequestWhenInUseAuthorization();

manager.LocationsUpdated += (locationSender, e) =>
{

    //get current locations
    manager.StopUpdatingLocation();
};
manager.StartUpdatingLocation();
```

Please notice that add the keys in `info.plist`: `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUsageDescription` on iOS11, if you want to deploy iOS10 add `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`.

In this way, there's no need to get metadata from `CGImageSource` when you pick photos from camera.